# c# Regex with look ahead failing

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to parse the boundary marker from email messages using RegEx in C#.

The data is in one of the formats:

```
 boundary=\"--==_mimepart_5c1ceb26ac136_211222489141168988\";
 boundary=\"----------=_1545338372-18873-1534\"
```

using:

```
string pattern = "(-+.+)";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
string boundary = (from x in email where x.Contains("boundary=\"") select x).FirstOrDefault();
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(boundary);
```

I get the result of:

```
--==_mimepart_5c1ceb26ac136_211222489141168988\";
```

If I change the pattern to:

```
string pattern = "(-+.+)(?=\\\\)";
```

I get zero matches.  I've also tried "(-+.+)(\\)" and still get zero matches.  Using Regexer and Regex Storm, the pattern captures exactly what I need.  Can anyone help me sort out why this is failing?

Comment: Also, does your string contain those escape characters for some reason? I mean the raw string (take a look at the variable's value in text viewer in debug mode)

Comment: I think the last thing I said is the reason you're getting different results. In code, the string doesn't have those escape characters there but the way your IDE is showing you, it adds `\ `s to escape some characters so you can copy-paste easily. Try using `string pattern = "\"(-+.+)\""` and get `.Groups[1]`.

Comment: Try `"-[^\"]+"` regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you add that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @FurkanKambay When I use your pattern I get:
    \"--==_mimepart_5c1ceb2ac136_211222489141168988\"
Unfortunately the extra escaped quotes don't match the string I'm searching for.

Comment: @CarlForgey yeah I used a capture group. You're supposed to access it as I showed or modify the pattern to use lookahead and lookbehinds instead and get the matched string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may match the string you need with

```
var pattern = "-[^\"]+";
```

It willl match a `-` and then 1 or more chars other than `"`.

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=-%5B%5E%22%5D%2B&i=%20boundary%3D%22--%3D%3D_mimepart_5c1ceb26ac136_211222489141168988%22%3B%0D%0A%20boundary%3D%22----------%3D_1545338372-18873-1534%22)